# What does "no-fault" auto insurance coverage look like for vehicle damage?

Tags: insurance, new-jersey

I am asking specifically about New Jersey, which is a no-fault state.

Everything I've been seeing online about no-fault insurance refers specifically to PIP and the source of coverage for any injuries and lost wages from an auto accident.  I'm want to know, though, whether the no-fault concept carries over to damage to the automobile as well, or if that responsibility falls on the insurance of the at-fault party?

The specific situation causing me to wonder this is that somebody hit my car in a parking lot while nobody was in my car.

Answer (score 2):

"No-fault" insurance only covers medical bills and income loss by you and your passengers. Coverage for damage to your vehicle comes either from your insurance company if you have comprehensive / collision coverage, or from the liability policy of the other party, if they are at fault. What the law does is impose the burden for compensation on the individual's insurance company, that is, they have to pay regardless of who is at fault.

Comment: So if I'm in a three way wreck, and I have Geko Insurance, another involved driver has Progress Flo, and a third at fault driver has EveryState, Geko will pay me, Flo will pay it's driver and State will pay its customer, as well as Geko and Progress Flo to the tune of the damages paid out to their customers?

Comment: @hszmv I think that's a different question. You might consider asking it.